# Laravel 5 error when downloading illuminate\http

Tags: laravel

I tried to install illuminate\http and i got this error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmServiceProvider' not found

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
[--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-
packages] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

More than this, in my app.php file in the providers zone i see these:

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
```

i expected to see something like 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider'
Is this normal ?
Ho can i install illuminate\http ? is there any other way ? like manually ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "illuminate/html" not "illuminate/http"

> Illuminate/http comes by default with laravel

Open your project directory

Run

```
composer require illuminate/html
```

After the package downloaded Open

> config/app.php

Under providers add this

```
 Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and Under aliases add these

```
'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

So your code would look like this

```
'providers' => [
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade:class,
],
```

Comment: Have you added the FormFacade?

Comment: {!!form::open()!!}

 {!!form::close()!!}

Comment: Dude, in the aliases you added as "Form" not "form". use it as {!! Form::open() !!} not {!! form::open() !!}